# 19.10: Troubleshoot failed (wired Ethernet) internet connection when DNS works properly?

Tags: networking, ethernet

I'm connecting to a corporate internet for the first time using an Ethernet cable. The connection works for everyone else, but not my Ubuntu 19.1 laptop.

After troubleshooting, there doesn't seem to be any issue with DNS since my laptop resolves the domains and I can access these IP addresses on my phone. I can't ping any website with either the IP address or domain name from my laptop. I am able to ping the default route.

```
$ host google.com
google.com has address 64.233.185.102
google.com has address 64.233.185.138
google.com has address 64.233.185.113
google.com has address 64.233.185.139
google.com has address 64.233.185.100
google.com has address 64.233.185.101
google.com has IPv6 address 2607:f8b0:4002:c09::64
google.com mail is handled by 40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx.l.google.com.

$ ping 72.30.35.10
PING 72.30.35.10 (72.30.35.10) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 72.30.35.10 ping statistics ---
164 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 166900ms

$ network-test
INFO: This system has exactly one default route
INFO: Host localhost answers to ICMP pings
INFO: Loopback interface is working properly
INFO: The enp0s31f6 interface is up
INFO: The enp0s31f6 interface has IP address 10.248.19.128 assigned
INFO: The enp0s31f6 interface has tx and rx packets.
WARN: The wlp4s0 interface is down
INFO: The router 10.248.19.11 is reachable
INFO: This system is configured to use nameserver 127.0.0.53
INFO: Host 127.0.0.53 answers to ICMP pings
INFO: Dns server 127.0.0.53 resolved correctly www.debian.org
INFO: The nameserver configured for this system works properly
WARN: System does not seem to reach Internet host www.debian.org through ICMP
ERR: Cannot access web server at Internet host www.debian.org (port 80)

$ ping 10.248.19.11
PING 10.248.19.11 (10.248.19.11) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.248.19.11: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=1.09 ms
64 bytes from 10.248.19.11: icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=1.28 ms
64 bytes from 10.248.19.11: icmp_seq=3 ttl=255 time=1.61 ms
64 bytes from 10.248.19.11: icmp_seq=4 ttl=255 time=0.918 ms
```

```
> 2: enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc
> fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
>     link/ether 12:0a:57:4c:e7:13 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
>     inet 10.248.19.128/24 brd 10.248.19.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s31f6
>        valid_lft 86104sec preferred_lft 86104sec
>     inet6 fe80::9f93:f86b:b5c4:b9b5/64 scope link noprefixroute 
>        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

What additional troubleshooting steps can I perform to identify why I can't ping websites?

```
 $sudo lshw -C network
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 3a
       serial: a4:34:d9:bc:64:de
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.3.0-40-generic firmware=36.77d01142.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:128 memory:f1000000-f1001fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 21
       serial: 12:0a:57:4c:e7:13
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.13-3 ip=10.248.3.104 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:124 memory:f1200000-f121ffff

$ host www.ebay.com
www.ebay.com is an alias for slot9428.ebay.com.edgekey.net.
slot9428.ebay.com.edgekey.net is an alias for e9428.b.akamaiedge.net.
e9428.b.akamaiedge.net has address 72.246.253.92
```

> $ ping -c 5 8.8.8.8 PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
>
> --- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics --- 5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4104ms

I never had issues with wireless. Connected to my phones internet now.

Comment: Is this Ubuntu, or Debian?

Comment: It's Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: Does the laptop's ethernet interface work on other networks? Before I go digging for more clues, boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and see if it works on the corp. connection.

Comment: Idk I dont have access to another wired network. I dont have enough internet now to download an iso.

Comment: Go ahead and try booting to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and see if it works. If it works, then there's something specific about your Ubuntu installation that's broken. If it doesn't work, then the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I booted to lubuntu flash drive. It has the same issue. Dns worked but cant ping. Maybe its the NIC card driver? (I dont have a working LAN to check) Or maybe this network doesnt support linux.

Comment: Its Thinkpad x260

Comment: With it plugged into the corp network, edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network`. What network icon do you see... a question mark? Let's see if you've got a r8168/r8169 LAN card. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: Also do `ping -c 5 8.8.8.8` and `host www.ebay.com`.

Comment: Do you have wireless access somewhere?

Comment: The `lshw` command shows `size` as 100Mbit/s, when it should be 1Gb. That usually means a bad ethernet cable. It should be a cat 5e or cat 6 cable. The ping not working may be related to the corp network blocking them. If you have the correct cable, contact the corp IT folks for additional help.